# EntityList / EntityCollection - MVVM Example

Tags: mvvm, entity-framework-4, ria

I'm working with the new EntityList in the April toolkit to expose a collection in a ViewModel.  I also have FK exposed as EntityCollections.

I thought I would expose the collection as IEnumerable, which handles the exposure of a collection using generic interfaces.  That leaves the FK that I bind to grids/list .... can I create an enumerable with an embeded object using EntityCollection?  Is this the "right" way?

I've also built a number of user controls, each with their own viewmodel.  Does this mean the page should have a viewmodel, with the other viewmodels aggregated within it?  Should each control stand on it's own, instanciating it's own viewmodel when the user control is embedded in a page?

I know that I could also jump over to POCO classes, but I'm on a tight deadline, and would like to minimize all the plumbing code.

I'm also a newbie on testing code, but I'm hoping that when I have more time, I can go back and fill that in.

So much to learn, so little time!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to combine the Entity Framework 4 with MVVM.